# What benefits do the different gems provide? How does quality boost it?

Tags: diablo-iii

What benefits do the amethyst, emerald, topaz and ruby provide when socketed?  How is this affected by the quality of the gem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complete details for each gem type and quality level appear on the official guide: http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem/

In short:

```
           Helm       Weapon            Other
Amethyst   +%Life     +Life per hit     +Vitality
Emerald    +Gold      +Critical Damage  +Dexterity
Ruby       +XP        +Damage           +Strength
Topaz      +MF        +Thorns           +Intelligence
```

+MF means Magic Find.

Comment: Also the quality or level of the gem refers to the level the Jeweler needs to be to work with it. They are , in the order of lowest to highest: Flawed(1), Normal(2), Flawless(3), Perfect(4), Radiant(5), Square(6), Flawless Square(7), Perfect Square(8), Radiant Square(9), Star (10), Flawless Star(10), Perfect Star(10), Radiant Star(10). Jewels from levels 1 to 5 are dropped in game, anything above needs to be combined.

Comment: Actually, jewels from 1 to 7 are dropped in game. Perfect Square and higher ones must be combined or purchased.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.mokhtarguides.com/2012/02/08/what-you-should-know-about-diablo-3-gems/) website has a pretty good guide to gems.

1. **Amethysts** give you life percentage when socketed into helms. When socketed in other equipment, amethysts give you Vitality. When socketed into weapons it gives lifesteal.
2. **Rubies** increases the experience you gain per kill when socketed into helms. When socketed in other equipment, rubies give you Strength. When socketed into weapons gives +max/mix damage.
3. **Emeralds** give you extra gold from monsters when socketed into helms. When socketed in other equipment, emeralds give you Dexterity. When socketed into weapons it gives crit chance.
4. **Topazes** give you better change of finding magical items when socketed into helms. When socketed in other equipment, topazes give you Intelligence. When socketed into weapons it returns damage taken.